# $C_c^{\infty}(F^{\ast})$ is spanned by functions $\chi_{\ast}(ax) $

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a nonarchimedean local field, and $C_c^{\infty}(F^{\ast})$ the vector space of locally constant complex valued functions of compact support.  For $\chi$ a character of $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$, extend $\chi$ to a function $\chi_{\ast}$ on all of $F^{\ast}$ by setting $\chi_{\ast}(x) = 0$ for $x$ outside $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$.

I have read that $C_c^{\infty}(F^{\ast})$ is spanned by the functions of the form $\chi_{\ast}(ax)$ for $\chi$ a character of $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$ and $a \in F^{\ast}$, and was wondering why this is.

The translations $\chi_{\ast}(ax)$ give you functions on $\{x \in F^{\ast} : \nu(x) = -\nu(a) \}$.

If $U_n = 1 + \mathfrak p^n$ is contained in the kernel of $\chi$, then if $x_1, ... , x_t$ is a set of representatives of $U_n$ in $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$, then

$$\chi  = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \chi(x_i) \textrm{Char}(x_iU_n)$$

I need to somehow isolate the characteristic functions of the cosets $x_iU_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you need to isolate the characteristic functions of the cosets of $1+\mathfrak p^n$ in $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$.  Let $m = [\mathcal O_F^{\ast} : 1 + \mathfrak p^n]$, and let $U_1, ... , U_m$ be the cosets of $1+\mathfrak p^n$ in $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$.   There are $m$ distinct characters of $\mathcal O_F^{\ast}$ which are trivial on $1+\mathfrak p^n$, and each of these is a sum of the form

$$c_1 \textrm{Char}(U_1) + \cdots + c_m \textrm{Char}(U_m)$$

Characters of an abelian group constitute a linearly independent set, and so they form a basis for the $m$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{C} \textrm{Char}(U_1) + \cdots + \mathbb{C} \textrm{Char}(U_m)$.